# Linear algebra on python (gaussian elimination)

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am a newbie to python and I came across some issues while I was working on [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) using python. I got the error message:

`IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4`.

How should I correct it?

```
A = array(  [[3,-1,-1,0,0,0],
            [-1,4,-1,-1,0,0],
            [0,0,-1,-1,4,-1],
            [0,0,0,-1,-1,3]], float)

v = array([5,5,0,0,0,0],float)

N = len(v)

for m in range(N):
    Div = A[m,m]
    A[m,:]/= Div
    v[m]/= Div

for i in range(m + 1, N):
    mult= A[i,m]
    A[i,:]-= mult*A[m,:]
    v[i]-= mult*v[m]


x = empty(N,float)
for m in range(N-1,-1,-1):
    x[m] = v[m]
for i in range(m + 1,N):
    x[m]-= A[m,i]*x[i]

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you have a matrix of size 4x6, which means your indices for each dimension of your array go from 0 to 3 and 0 to 5 respectively.

Then you have a for loop going from 0 to range(N), where N is a length of a 6 element array. This is the loop with m as an iterator.

Finally, you have (what I assume is meant to be) an inner loop going from m+1 to N and you use that index in A for the rows:

```
 for i in range(m + 1, N):
    mult= A[i,m]
```

The variable i here will be going to N (which is 6 in this case) each time, but your A matrix can only go 0 to 3 there in the rows index.

In summary:

A is a 4x6 matrix
N is length 6
you are trying to access A[4,m] in the following loop (as well as A[5,m] and A[6,m]:

```
for i in range(m + 1, N):
    mult= A[i,m]
```

when you can only at most reach A[3,m].

EDIT:

Actually, the error happens a little earlier than I mentioned previously:

```
for m in range(N):
   Div = A[m,m]
```

Here, A[m,m] will not work for m > 4, but m in range(N) will take m to 5.